# package.json not found after npm install and npm start. The project was able to run before I pushed it to github

Tags: node.js, reactjs, git, npm, version-control

Basically I have a react project that was working fine before I pushed it to Github. I think the `package.json` file is now in the projects `.gitignore` file.

How do I check if this is the case and how do I remove it from `.gitignore`?
No matter what I do, It can't find the `package.json` file?

I have tried various forms of `npm install`, `npm install -g express` and many other commands that are top answers to stack overflow questions that ask this question. When I `npm start` it I recieve the following errors

```
 npm ERR! code ENOENT
 npm ERR! syscall open
 npm ERR! path /Users/wmannix/dev_repos/optic_link/integrator-ui/package.json
 npm ERR! errno -2
 npm ERR! enoent ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 
'/Users/wmannix/dev_repos/optic_link/integrator-ui/package.json'
 npm ERR! enoent This is related to npm not being able to find a file.
 npm ERR! enoent
```

I didn't write a command to ignore this file though so is it a possibility it could of done this automatically? I'm thinking this because it wasn't able to find the package.json file as soon as I committed and pushed my branch containing the react project to a remote GitHub branch.

If this isn't a possibility, is there anything else I can try to get package.json back into my project?

Comment: where do you run the command? to check the gitignore open it with a file editor, it is not encrypted

Comment: **1)** Run `git log -p .gitignore` to show the commit history for the _.gitignore_ file. **2)** Copy the SHA-1 of the earlier commit in which your _.gitignore_ file` did not include _package.json_. **3)** Restore the earlier version of _.gitignore_ by running `git checkout <enter-sha-1-from-step-2-here> -- .gitignore` **4)** Finally `git commit` the restored version of _.gitignore_

Answer (score 0):

> How do I check if this is the case and how do I remove it from .gitignore?

```
# Edit the file in any text editor or:
cat .gitignore

# filter only the package.json
cat .gitignore | grep package
```

---

Another way is to printout list of ignored file and in which ignore file or level they are defined

```
$ git check-ignore -v *
$ git check-ignore -v **/**
```

---

The other way around - print list of files which are marked as ignored in the `.gitignore` but are tracked by git

```
# Print out files which the pattern is marked as ignored but git does track them
# This can be done by explicitly adding them to git with git add -f
git ls-files -i --exclude-from=.gitignore
```